# I need to have menu items disabled in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, drop-down-menu

This is my code for my mobile navigation.

```
//For Mobile Menu:
<style>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $(".menuclick").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".menu_box").slideToggle("fast");
            return false;
      });
});
</style>
```

I need the list that appears to not be visible in mobile until the mobile menu button is clicked.

Does anyone have a quick fix for this?

Comment: why don't you just have it as display none in the css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Best would be hide it using css**, just add style or a class with `display:none` to the element

*OR*

You can do `trigger` click event after you bind click event, that will hide `menu_box`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $(".menuclick").click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(".menu_box").slideToggle("fast");
      });
}).trigger('click');
```

Also use either `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;`

Comment: Thanks. I actually just came to that conclusion about 2 seconds ago. There was a class hidden in my stylesheet. Glad I was correct. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to display:none, and toggle will do the rest.

```
<div class="menu_box" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you using both prevent default and return false?

Comment: Please don't advocate inline style. Use an external stylesheet!

Comment: jquery will put display property inline anyways

Comment: Just because jQuery does it doesn't mean you should ;) There's a difference between hard coding the style inline and programmatically doing it.

Comment: @RUJordan is right I guess... just add it to the external style sheet. but if that gives you problems... well... just inline it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could either have a default style `display:none` on the element, or use JavaScript or jQuery.

CSS way:

```
.menu_box { display:none; }
```

jQuery:

```
$(".menu_box").css("display","none");
```

Mandatory vanilla solution:

Grab all elements by class, iterate the array of elements, and apply the style.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("menu_box");
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++) x[i].style.display = "none";
```